# Access field of object in array (state) in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, setstate, use-effect

In React component I have a state called projectTypes which is an array of objects:

```
const [projectTypes, setProjectTypes] = useState([])
```

This state is set inside an useEffect hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
...
  setProjectTypes(...)
...
})
```

with information received from a fetch to the server. That information is displayed inside a table and everything is working as expected.

I want to check a field inside the first element (an object) of the state array:

```
projectTypes[0]._id
```

To be sure that I'm accessing projectTypes when it already has values, I'm using another hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
...
  console.log(projectTypes[0]);
  console.log(projectTypes[0]._id);
...

}, [projectTypes]);
```

I have 2 questions:

1. Is this the right procedure to be sure that when accessing the state it already has values inside: creating a new hook with [projetTypes] as the 2nd parameter?
2. Inside this second hook, if I only use the first console.log - console.log(projectTypes[0]) - everything works as expected and the first object of the state is printed to the console with an _id field. But using the second one - console.log(projectTypes[0]._id) - results in an error: "TypeError: Cannot read property '_id' of undefined". Why can I access the object inside the state array just fine, and print it with all its fields, but if I try to access one of its fields, I get an error?

Comment: Yes, that's the common thing to create multiple useEffect functions. Although it has the ```projectTypes``` as a dependency array, remember that it will call it when the component is mounted as well and at that time, the data has not been fetched yet. So you will still need to do a check here: ```if (!projectTypes) return;```

Comment: You can inside ```useEffect``` add null check ```projectTypes[0] && projectTypes[0]._id```. Anyway you can also create another state which would look like this ```const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true)``` and then just reverse ```loading``` inside your fetch function

Comment: @szczocik, I wasn't aware that when passing a 2nd argument with the dependencies array, the function passed to useEffect would also run when the component is mounted. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

As the effect is called whenever any of its dependencies update, You can do it with as single effect.

within the effect, check if data within it is valid, if yes, do something, else continue.

like

```
useEffect(() => {
    if(projectTypes && projectTypes.length >0){
        //do something
    }
}, [projectTypes]);
```

Comment: I think I understand what could happen, but still, to fully understand it, @Adithya, can you elaborate on why we need to check both conditions: projectTypes && projectTypes.length > 0 ? Could you provide a situation in which we would pass the first test but not the second?

Comment: both checks are not necessary if you have an initial state that is an array (`useState([])`) and you are sure it'll be an array even after any update. in case you have null to indicate empty value (`useState(null)`, often the case with `useRef`). you'll make first check to check it is not null, so  that `projectTypes.length` would't throw `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null`